# Is there any solution to generate code in google authenticator without confirmation?

Tags: freeradius, google-authenticator

I have recently installed freeradius with google authenticator. Freeradius integrated with cisco asa for 2-factor authentication of VPNs.
We have 2000 employees who want to use this service. 
The problem is that to generate the code, each user must log in at least once and enter the code after scanning QR code. But the process is very difficult for 2000 people. Is there a solution to automate this process? Can we just send the QR code to each person and verification process happens on the first login?
Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: I'm not really sure what this is asking.  So the user scans a QR code to get the token seed... then they get the OTP to authenticate to the VPN service, which seems fine, that's how 2FA usually works.

But you seem to be asking whether there's a way to convert this 2FA to 1FA by remembering that the user has submitted at least one good code, which is fairly trivial to do in FreeRADIUS, but... why use the google authenticator at all??

Comment: First of all thanks Arran.
That problem resolved. No, I have 2fa and it is working.
my new problem is for generating code for each person, the users have to log in to Linux, type "google-authenticator" command and generate code for themselves. But I have 1000 users who are going to be authenticated through the domain server. It is not possible to do that for all of them. Do you have a solution for this?
Thanks again

Comment: Is this the OTP or the Token Seed?

Comment: It is OTP. 
I want to integrate freeradius with AD to authenticate VPN users.